# Better Binding for DataTrigger

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a `TextBlock` and I want to set the property `Visibility` to `Collapsed` when the `TextBlock` has no text. I wonder me, for sure there should be a better way to check if the `Lenght` of the property `Text` is equal than 0.

```
                        <TextBlock Name="TextBlockHeader" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Header}" Margin="0,0,0,25">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBlockHeader, Path=Text.Length}" Value="0">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
```

Here I have to define a name for the `TextBlock` and I can reference it in the `Datatrigger` `Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBlockHeader, Path=Text.Length}"`
But how can I achieve the same without having to define a name for the `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would usually use Triggers instead of DataTriggers, and compare the Text property to either `null` or an empty string.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

As the TextBlock class seems to coerce the Text property value to be non-null, it may be sufficient to have only the second Trigger for an empty string.

Comment: @Clemens I don't think the `sys:String.Empty` part is necessary: `Value=""` should work just as well and avoids the need for the namespace declaration.